Common misconceptions when discussing language
In the answers and comments of this site there are some recurring kinds of reasoning that I am afraid are misconceptions about what language is and how it is studied. I believe it would be useful to clarify some points, not to have to address them again and again.
The word XXX is ugly Opinions are often offered about the fact that a word or a phrase “is ugly”, “sounds bad”, “is cacophonous” and the like. Now, while the experience of a native speaker of a language is invaluable, not every personal taste is an addition to a discussion about a linguistic phenomenon. Rather, in general such remarks are no more interesting than “I like coffee” or “I dislike jazz” and no especially useful when attempting a scientific discussion of language.
I never heard/always hear XXX This is a bit better than the previous case, but I'd confine such remarks strictly to comments, since it is not always clear whether they reflect a comprehensive understanding of language or an accident of the writer's idiolect. And I'm saying so for myself first: I am not exactly a child, but I still learn that some words or linguistic uses are especially frequent or especially rare in my town / circle of acquaintances / texts I read, and so not representative of Italian in general.
The dictionary says so! This is a rather subtle point, and in a sense the opposite of the previous ones. We all agree that reliable sources are of the utmost importance, so when we are discussing lexicon there is no better source than good, authoritative dictionaries (for instance Battaglia, Treccani, Zingarelli, De Mauro, Devoto-Oli, Sabatini-Coletti, rather than anonymous, web-based ones; and Battisti-Alessio or Cortelazzo-Zolli for etymology).
But it is important to understand what dictionaries actually are, since it seems that some people have some misconceptions about this. Dictionaries are not prescriptive authorities, they do not fix what can or cannot be written and said. They register the use of present and past speakers, and even that they don't do in real time.
In a Crusca linguist's words to a schoolboy:

È così che funziona: non sono gli studiosi, quelli che fanno i vocabolari, a decidere quali parole nuove sono belle o brutte, utili o inutili. Quando una parola nuova è sulla bocca di tutti (o di tanti), allora lo studioso capisce che quella parola è diventata una parola come le altre e la mette nel vocabolario.
(It works like this: it's not scholars, those who make dictionaries, that decide which new words are good or bad, useful or useless. When a new word is used by all (or many) people, then the scholar understands that the word has become a word like all the other ones and puts it in the dictionary.) [My translation]

Many people say so! The simple fact than many people say or write * metereologico rather than meteorologico, * non c'è ne sono rather than non ce ne sono, * colluttorio rather than collutorio, * se io sarei rather than se io fossi, and so on, does not make these forms immediately and universally part of standard Italian. They have to become so widespread as to become (and be perceived as) a new norm, but since many other people feel these forms to be incorrect, they effectively are.
It is true that many single words and grammatical constructions began as “errors” (crollare used to mean “to oscillate”, not “to fall down”; after a negation one was supposed to use alcuno rather than nessuno; bistecca was a weird adaptation of “beefsteak” and so on), and in a sense the whole of Italian is a “wrong” form of Latin, where everybody ignores the use of declensions and most Latin grammar, but it imposed itself as a new norm. It was a new, correct, vital language when most people began using it for everything from haggling at the market to writing love poetry. When metereologia and se io farei will be analogously widespread, they will be de facto correct. Now, they aren't.

I completely agree!

Vedi che non mi so spiegare, @Josh61? :-) Io non ho mai detto che dobbiamo dire «che "petaloso" o "un'ascoltata" sono espressioni della lingua italiana correnti e corrette». Se siano o meno “correnti” lo dicono le risposte, i commenti, i link con cui contribuiamo a questo sito: non a caso, le risposte non sono – e non devono essere – solo della forma “sì/no”. [segue]

Quanto a “corretto/scorretto”, dico addirittura che non è proprio una categoria appartenente alla linguistica moderna: sarebbe come dire che è “corretto” che un luccio sia viola. Lo è, non lo è, lo è una certa percentuale, lo sono in una certa zona geografica: ci sono fatti, statistiche, ricostruzioni storiche etc. Ma che c'entra la correttezza? Mica ci occupiamo del galateo.

Might the user who downvoted offer an opinion? Downvotes without a comment are especially pointless here on Meta, whose main function is to discuss things.

While I agree that "correct/uncorrect" is not a linguistic category, I think that it is a "didactic" category. We should not use them while discussing the fine point of the language, but I think that when we talk about the new fad that appeared today in TV and will disappear tomorrow saying "it's not grammatically correct Italian although it is used among xxx" is a fair assessment. Especially since many of the people asking questions are just learning Italian I think that a descriptivist stance might do them a disservice. On other questions a higher level of sophistication is warranted

I understand your position, @DenisNardin, but even when I learn a language I appreciate a more nuanced discourse. Or perhaps it is just a question of phrasing things; rather than alluding to a hypothetical, absolute “correctness”, I'd say something like “the traditional rule says so and so; nowadays there is a tendency to do so and so else...” and so on.

@Josh61: Where did I say that «there is a tendency to saying "patatoso" or "inzupposo"»? I never even have heard these words. Please comment on, or even refute, what I say, not something else altogether.

@Josh61: I don't know about “patatoso” nor “inzupposo”. If you mean petaloso, I referred there to what Crusca said, that is, exactly the opposite of a tendency etc.: the gist – but of course Crusca says this way better – is “let's wait and see what happens with this word, as with any other one”.

Qualche utile spunto: https://linguaenauti.com/2016/04/18/cronache-da-italianocorretto/ («l’italiano corretto è una definizione intrinsecamente impossibile. La nostra lingua fa un po’ come le pare e non possiamo che constatarlo più o meno sconsolati, perché tra la grammatica prescrittiva e quella d’uso esiste una breccia in continua e imprevedibile evoluzione»).

Quindi se ho capito bene il punto è che: 1. "Suona male" non è motivo per dire che qualcosa sia sbagliato (mi ricorda discussioni a proposito di "a me mi") 2. "Mai sentito" è una ragione non valida (e mi pare giusto). 3. Anche la presenza, o no, di una parola/espressione nei vocabolari ha i suoi limiti (il che ha senso). Se penso alla parola impapigliato posso immaginare come ci possa essere chi dice che suona male, non l'ha mai sentita e non la trova nel Treccani. Se qualche straniero chiedesse se sia corretto usarla che gli direste?

Interessante domanda, @ErikvanDoren! Ovviamente non è che intendessi sminuire l'importanza dei dizionari, che sono sempre la risorsa fondamentale per quanto riguarda il lessico. Se “impapigliato” non è presente nei dizionari, significa che i lessicografi non hanno ritenuto che sia sufficientemente usato da includerlo. Quindi all'ipotetico straniero si potrebbe far presente appunto che non è una parola universalmente diffusa e compresa, e poi spiegargli in quale ambito la si potrebbe usare (io non lo so: è un termine di Camilleri?).

Impapigliato = impaperato, non so quanto sia diffuso, io sono veneto e qui lo usiamo. Ma parenti di Roma capiscono il senso anche se forse solo dal contesto. A proposito del "suona male", recentemente è stata la mia spiegazione sul perché della d eufonica (dopotutto è appunto "eufonica" per qualcosa ed in quel caso c'è poco da fare).

@Josh61, la mia zona e' a cavallo tra il vicentino e trevigiano, ma sentito anche al di fuori come termine. Una ricerca frettolosa in google mi da' solo due risultati, uno riferito al Camilleri ed un altro ad un consigliere del comune di Tropea (???). Non avendo il tempo di andare a cercare origini e diffusione del termine, di piu' non posso dirti.

@Josh61, giusto per curiosita' (forse e' un salto un po troppo lungo) ho ficcato in google la parola papigliare e mi e' saltato fuori col siglificato di parpagliare (senza la s) nel "Vocabolario italiano, e latino per uso delle scuole di tutti gli stati del Piemonte", roba del 1735 (e come curiosita' porta pure la data in numeri romani nella versione con la C retrograda). Ma al di la' di questo non vado ad indagare oltre, lo lascio come briciola, eventualmente...

@ErikvanDoren, Josh61, forse vale la pena di farne una domanda vera e propria.

Onestamente non vedo cosa ci sia di sbagliato nel dire "questa parola non l'ho quasi mai sentita usare anche se compare nel vocabolario quindi è scritta in modo corretto / utilizzabile / altro". Dare un'indicazione di frequenza dell'uso di certe parole è un atto utile nei confronti di chi impara. Ricordo ad esempio una discussione su Duolingo riguardo a macchina/auto/automobile e quanto spesso si usi ciascuna delle tre.

@AndreaLazzarotto: Che io, tu o uno chiunque di noi non abbia mai sentito una certa parola dà sì un'informazione, ma non poi molto rilevante, visto che ognuno di noi è uno solo fra decine di milioni di parlanti italiano. Per loro natura, i siti Stack Exchange aspirano a raccogliere informazioni oggettive, comprovabili, confermate da fonti. Che dalle parti mie si dica più “proseguire” che “seguitare” può avere il suo interesse, ma non ha nessuna di quelle caratteristiche di oggettività ed è per questo che propongo di riservarlo ai commenti..

@DaG, questa community parla di lingua, non di informatica... non si può pensare di raggiungere esattamente lo stesso livello di "oggettività" nel 100% dei casi. Riguardo a cosa ne sappia un italiano della frequenza d'uso delle parole, c'è anche da dire che la televisione influenza pesantemente l'uso del linguaggio nella popolazione. Molti di noi guardano la TV, quindi ogni tanto si rendono conto di espressioni nuove o cose che cadono in disuso.

Grazie per la risposta, @AndreaLazzarotto, ma che c'entra l'informatica? Che c'entra il 100%? Il concetto di "norma" che menzionavo è un concetto chiave della sociolinguistica. Se vuoi ti posso dare qualche estremo bibliografico per approfondire.

Le norme della lingua italiana stabiliscono quale debba essere la frequenza d'uso di certe parole nella popolazione? Urca, questa davvero non la sapevo... linka pure che così leggo un po'. :)

@AndreaLazzarotto: Urca, non mi so proprio spiegare: non ho mai detto che “le norme della lingua italiana stabiliscono quale debba essere la frequenza d'uso di certe parole nella popolazione”. Dico che i linguisti hanno un concetto ben attestato di “norma” che non c'entra necessariamente con soglie di frequenza d'uso o simili (concetti che hai tirato in ballo tu, non io).

@AndreaLazzarotto Vedi per esempio la voce “norma” nel Dizionario di linguistica curato da G.L. Beccaria, la voce sullo stesso argomento nell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani, il secondo volume (“La variazione e gli usi”) dell'Introduzione all'italiano contemporaneo di A.A. Sobrero, Sociolinguistica dell'italiano contemporaneo di G. Berruto, giusto per cominciare. I concetti di norma, uso e varietà nelle lingue sono un'area di studio e ricerca molto ampia, che è difficile ridurre a due battute.

Ok, fammi capire, chi è che ha scritto che dire che una parola è scarsamente utilizzata non va bene perché è irrilevante o non oggettivo? Se di colpo cambi argomento parlando di norme la discussione non andrà a finire da nessuna parte.

@AndreaLazzarotto, non sto cambiando di colpo argomento: se leggi quello che ho scritto nel mio proclama qui in alto ho usato più volte la parola “norma”, che per i linguisti ha un senso ben preciso, e non si riduce a una frequenza statistica (che pure ha interesse, ma è un'altra cosa).

@AndreaLazzarotto: Detto in soldoni: nessun parlante italiano sa quale sia la frequenza di “occaso” rispetto a “tramonto”, ma tutti sanno che il secondo fa parte della norma contemporanea, il primo no, pur non essendo “sbagliato”, “brutto” etc.
